# How to get a variable from parent view in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the views : 'default.blade.php', 'about.blade.php', 'contacts.blade.php'.

'about.blade.php' and 'contacts.blade.php' extends 'default.blade.php'.

How can I define the variable $root in 'default.blade.php' and use it in all views which extends 'default.blade.php'? 
(I must to use only the blade, not the view composers, the controllers, etc)

So,

'default.blade.php':

```
@php
    $root = 'RootDirectory';
@endphp
```

'about.blade.php' and 'contacts.blade.php':

```
@extends('layouts.default')
{{ $root }}
```

Throws an error like 'Undefined variable "root"'

Comment: "I must to use only the blade, not the view composers, the controllers, etc" , why? Can you please explain the use case ?

Comment: Сustomer wants to get all pages from laravel application just like blade template, which can build to static html :-) Vendor do not wants all functionality(composers, controllers etc) of application, although application is ready.

Comment: who can explain me, why my questions minused?

Answer (score 2):

For global variable you may use **viewComposer**:

1. create file `app/Http/Composers/RootComposer.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Composers;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
   class RootComposer {
      public function __construct(){
         $this->root= 'RootDirectory';
      }
      public function compose(View $view){
         $view->with('root', $this->root);
      }
   }
   ```
2. create file `app/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
   use View;
   class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
      public function boot(){
         View::composers(['App\Http\Composers\RootComposer' => '*']);
      }
   }
   ```
3. add this row in cofig/app.php in providers array

   `App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,`

And use `$root` in all views

Comment: You forgot to tell him to add this in providers array in config/app.php 
`\App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily share data to all your views using the view facade's share method. You can do this in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('root', 'rootDirectory');
    }
}
```

Then in any of your view files, you can access the data directly:

`{{$root}}`

You can also pass an array of data:

`View::share('data', ['root'=>'rootDirectory','others'=>'otherDirectory']);`

Then assess them like:
`{{$data['root']}}` or `{{$data['otherDirectory']}}`

You can find this in the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views